# How can you determine if a Coffeescript script is being run as a script vs being required in a module?

Tags: javascript, process, coffeescript

I have a coffeescript file with code I'd like to be requirable by other scripts, but I also would like it to be run as a standalone script.

What is the most reliable way to determine if it's being required by another script vs being run directly?

e.g.
require("./myScript.coffee")
vs
coffee ./myScript.coffee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this on node? if so here are two options

A) using the call stack

```
stack = new Error().stack
```

B) using require.cache

Check if your script is in the require.cache list. For example [here](https://github.com/TeamMentor/TM_4_0_Design/blob/5a36a708c37781afe9f1a199f4903422aa7bb886/node/tests/server.test.coffee#L26-L34) is a unit test that finds a particular script on the current require.cache, and removes it

```
    for file in require.cache.keys()
      if file.contains(['node/server.coffee']) or  file.contains(['node-cov/server.coffee'])
        pathToApp = file
        break

    require.cache[pathToApp].assert_Is_Object()
    delete require.cache[pathToApp]

    app = require '../server'
```

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to include this line logic check before the 'standalone script execution'

```
if process.argv[1].toString().indexOf('myScript.coffee') != -1
    # Standalone script code here
```